# Edict about code blocks and decomplied code

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers

I recently posted an answer to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246089/minecraft-java-labg-nullpointerexception-when-connecting-to-server/246143?) question, and I used a fairly large code block. I haven't been on this stackexchange for very long so I wanted to know if someone could layout the edict surrounding using code. Furthermore the code that I posted is from a project that works to reverse engineer minecraft and provide the source code. I also wanted to know if this is looked down upon or should be avoided. If a question contains a game error is it best to just give a diagnosis? or should I try to be as precise as possible and post code snippets as well, Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/using-code-ticks-for-technical-term-highlighting-considered-harmful)

Comment: @MBraedley I'm not sure it is, that question is talking about the use of the code snippet markdown styling. My question is about weather large blocks of real code are welcome here or not and the legitimacy of obtaining the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm okay with small code-snippets in general *(I believe it's fair-use, though IANAL)*, but only if it actually adds something to your answer.

In your case, I don't think it does.  Knowing the `NullPointerException` is caused by `this.b.getSession().getToken()` does not help solve the problem.